# jQuery Quicksand grid alignment issue (Bootstrap based website)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, quicksand

i'm having some issues integrating Quicksand filtering into my item list, not sure if it's js or css problem.

This is the URL to the page with the Quicksand filtering integrated:
http://yarday.com/pax

As you can see, if you try to select any filter option, the animation starts as it's going to align properly, then jumps out of grid at the end.

This is how the grid is supposed to show:
http://yarday.com/paxific

I'm assuming it could be a CSS issue, but i am also using two different versions of jQuery (using no conflict) so that's why i thought it could be an issue in the plugin.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately we need to see your actual relevant code *in the question* here to be able to help. Check out the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: Please paste code that shows the problem [in the question itself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People can't read or search for code on external sites, and when the problem is fixed the links will no longer make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info Tyler, i thought the code was visible from the URL.

Anyway, i think the issue was on the css filter navbar float, i got them to align properly now, even though it's still a bit jumpy at the end.